# How do I create a campaign based on a membership tag?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I would like to send an email to the member users of the 'A' tags in LIST.

In this API https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/campaigns/

Which parameter is used to set up to meet my needs?

thanks!

Comment: Please add something that you have tried with examples. You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question

Comment: I don't use api directly.
I'm using an sdk on github.
The sdk encapsulates the api. But I can't find a way to filter the tags accurately.
So go to the official api, but don't use it.

https://github.com/banana-j/bananaj

thank you!

Comment: I think I need an example, a json string with the parameters of the member tags

Comment: You can learn about http requests [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_requests.htm).

Comment: I know http requests. But I'm not sure what parameters the mailchimp campaign campaigns need to pass in

Comment: campaigns tags need parameters is what